# GDB pretty printers for Qt5

Tags: c++, python, qt, gdb, qt5

Where I can find gdb pretty printers for qt5?

I could find only for qt4 on kde developer site. Maybe somebody knows whether pretty printers for new version of Qt exist and where I can find them.

I know that it's possible to use latest version of QtCreator, but I need just plain python scripts for GDB.

Answer (score 8):

The pretty printers listed on https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Debugging/Debugging_with_GDB are only partially compatible with Qt 5. Some types (such a QByteArray) are not handled correctly.

Alex Merry has worked on Qt 5 pretty printers and [tried](https://codereview.qt-project.org/87052) to push these into the Qt5 Base packages (unfortunately it did not made it). For convenience, I have made his printers available at https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers

Comment: What version of gdb is required to use https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers ? when I try to use it on `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-75.el6)` I get 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/myusername/gdb/printers/qt5printers/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import gdb.printing
ImportError: No module named printing`

Comment: @bgoodr You need at least GDB 7.3 for the pretty printing module (https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=7b51bc51e108b017e45141b15d940514a31260f6, see also the NEWS file)

Comment: The KDevelop pretty-printers are now described at https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Debugging/Debugging_with_GDB#Improving_your_gdb_experience_for_KDE.2FQt_applications and are supposedly compatible with Qt5.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, the following (`gdbinit` + `*.py`) supports qt5 objects, and appears to be periodically updated:

https://invent.kde.org/kdevelop/kdevelop/-/tree/master/plugins/gdb/printers

https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/tree/master/plugins/gdb/printers

Comment: The good thing about these is that they support both Qt4 and Qt5, which is very helpful when you have to debug programs using different major versions of Qt.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know pretty printers are located here: http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python/

Also, GDB binaries with Python enabled can be found here. http://origin.releases.qt-project.org/gdb/

Comment: Those pretty printers are for libstdc++. The question was about pretty printers for Qt5