# What version of GDB provides the gdb.printing Python module?

Tags: python, gdb

I am trying to get pretty-printing to work under Qt5 but on RHEL6.6 using its gdb version:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-75.el6)
```

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/31766741/257924 which links to https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers which seems to provide the code to enable pretty printing on Qt5. But when I try it on my version of gdb on RHEL6.6, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/myusername/gdb/printers/qt5printers/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import gdb.printing
ImportError: No module named printing
```

From that, I conclude that possibly the gdb version (and/or the python build into it) just must be too old to provide the gdb.printing module, but that is the root of my question. How do I figure out which gdb version is necessary (meaning I have to download and build it myself) to get pretty-printing to work under Qt5?

I cannot upgrade to a newer RHEL system due to decisions made by others (the company I work for) and thus is irrelevant to this question.

The command:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

emits:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.6 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Comment: @l'L'l It might be just that. A coworker claims the error disappears when using gdb 7.11 or newer, but I need to confirm it still.

Comment: Confirmed http://stackoverflow.com/a/42584890/257924 answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gdb NEWS file, `gdb.printing` was added in version 7.3, with some additions to the module being made in later releases.

Comment: I partially confirmed this by downloading and building gdb 7.12.1 and retesting with the qt5 pretty printing gdb code and it seems to work properly.