# Cannot setup pretty printers for Qt5 for gdb

Tags: python, c++, qt, gdb, qt5

I've tried to get GDB pretty printers for Qt5. But I failed.

I already read the answer here: [GDB pretty printers for Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492290/gdb-pretty-printers-for-qt5).

I follow this github link: https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers
But when I ran the test program with gdb, it shows this error log

```
❯ gdb -q -ex break\ test -ex r ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11a9: file ../test.cpp, line 2.
Starting program: /home/thuongle/Git/build/temp/build/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, test (ba=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x10>) at ../test.cpp:2
2       void test(const QByteArray & ba) { }
```

In the past I was successful setup this but not for this time.

Comment: Have you tried it with a non-empty `test` function?

Comment: Just the same:
`Breakpoint 1, test (ba=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x48c3014824048b59>) at ../test.cpp:2`

Comment: I should have clarified to check the value of `ba` on different lines of the function.

Comment: Poor me, I am just doing the step without think cause it was successful in the past. But you got me, it works! Thank man

Comment: Maybe it's the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719198/1983398).

Comment: Thank for the info!